# Растягивание размера контейнера-родителя

Tags: html, css

В комментариях есть пояснения.
Там надо, скорее всего, избавиться от абсолютного позиционирования, как, не пойму пока.

```css
.head {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 200px;
}
.cont {
  background: #a1b1e1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  header
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
</div>
<!-- cont всегда должен растягиваться не завимо от контейнера .content, 
и нижняя его граница всегда  снизу окна браузера, 
даже если .content будет меньше его 
Дайте контейнеру .content высоту 1000 у увидите что .cont не тянется
-->
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfzngqfL/)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/kfzngqfL/17/), позиционирование элементов кардинально изменилось

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.head {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  height: 100px;
}
.cont {
  margin: 0;
  background: #a1b1e1;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.push {
  height: 110px;
}
.content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  header
</div>
<div class="cont">
  <div class="push"></div>
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
</div>
<!-- cont всегда должен растягиваться не завимо от контейнера .content, 
и нижняя его граница всегда  снизу окна браузера, 
даже если .content будет меньше его 
Дайте контейнеру .content высоту 1000 у увидите что .cont не тянется
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

[Обновила ответ](http://jsfiddle.net/kfzngqfL/15/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
header,
nav,
section,
article,
aside,
footer {
  display: block;
}
body {
  font: 12px/18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
header {
  top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
#content {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 100px;
  position: relative;
}
#content:after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
footer {
  top: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 150;
  _position: absolute;
  _top: expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollTop+ (document.documentElement.clientHeight-this.offsetHeight)));
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
.inside {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    header
  </header>
  <section id="content">
    <h2>Awesome content</h2>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <div class="inside">
      hjkhkj
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Идея с тестированием пользовательского скролла взята [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571573/css-footer-position-stick-to-bottom-of-browser)

Comment: Увы, при маленьком значении высоты div.content контейнер div.cont не тянется книзу =(

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вы используете абсолютное позиционирование для обертки контента? Если это было с целью того, чтобы .head не схлопывался потому, что вы дали ему float: left;, то добавьте еще overflow: hidden;

Теперь удалите абсолютное позиционирование у вашей обертки, .cont. - и проблема будет сразу же решена. Также высота .cont будет 100%.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.head {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
    height: 50px;
}
.cont {
    background: #a1b1e1;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.content {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #aaa;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Обёртка будет обрезать .content по своей высоте.

Comment: обертка (.cont) обрезать не будет (.content) по своей высоте потому, что высоту в данном случае задает внутренний блок(.content). Обертка(.cont) будет тянутся по высоте вложенного блока(.content). Если это не то, значит я не правильно понял задачу автора.

Comment: Попробуйте в примере автора сделать высоту 1000px для .content и добавить overflow:hiedden  для .cont, автор хочет, чтобы и .cont и .content становились 1000px.

Comment: Все, понял теперь) Спасибо за разъяснение. Сейчас исправлю свой ответ.

Comment: Только там есть ещё одно условие, .cont должен прилипнуть к низу, независимо от размера .content.

Comment: Еще раз подправил, высота обертки теперь со 100% высотой, независимо от размера высоты .content.

Comment: Теперь ещё сделайте так, чтобы .cont + .head не были по высоте больше 100%, иначе содержимое будет всегда вылезать за экран, и получится мой вариант 1 в 1 :)

Comment: Не выдержал) http://jsfiddle.net/nosensus/ypo9n6e0/ вот тут реализовал и прилепающий подвал и чтобы .head+.cont были в одной упряжке. Кстати, почему-то ресурс jsfiddle.net немного некорректно отображает тянучку высоты на 100%, поэтому сохраните код отдельно в notepadd++ и смотрите результат там.